# TLS 1.2 Handshake: How is the ECDHE public key signed by server?

Tags: hash, tls, key-exchange

I am dealing with a situation where a cipher option, such as **ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA**, is chosen for establishing a TLS connection. In this case, a server, when sending the **ServerKeyExchange** message to the client, is required to sign the ephemeral (EC) diffie hellman key using its ECDSA private key (associated with the public key certificate). The public key is first hashed before an ECDSA sign operation can be performance.

My question: how is the hashing algorithm determined during the handshake?

RFC 4492 which describes the application of ECC to TLS 1.2 has the following text to indicate how this algorithm is determined:

> "“All ECDSA computations MUST be performed according to ANSI X9.62 [7]
>   or its successors.  Data to be signed/verified is hashed, and the
>   result run directly through the ECDSA algorithm with no additional
>   hashing.  **The default hash function is SHA-1 [10]**, and sha_size
>   (see    Sections 5.4 and 5.8) is 20.  However, an alternative hash
>   function,    such as one of the new SHA hash functions specified in
>   FIPS 180-2    [10], may be used instead if the certificate containing
>   the EC public key explicitly      requires use of another hash
>   function.  (***The mechanism    for specifying the required hash
>   function has not been standardized***,    but this provision
>   anticipates such standardization and obviates the    need to update
>   this document in response.  Future PKIX RFCs may    choose, for
>   example, to specify the hash function to be used with a    public key
>   in the parameters field of subjectPublicKeyInfo.)”

However, if one refers to NIST Suite-B requirements for TLS 1.2 (RFC 5430), it is clear on the use of SHA256 and SHA384 for desired security level (since SHA1 is deprecated by NIST).

So, in TLS handshake, *how does one specify the use SHA256 in the above signing procedure ?*

Thanks,

Hari Tadepalli

Answer (score 4):

RFC 4492 specifies ECC for TLS1.0 and TLS1.1. It does not cover TLS1.2 because it was written before TLS1.2; notice that 4492 is less than 5246. **RFC 5246** TLS1.2 changes the signature structure for all signing algorithms including ECDSA, and also adds a Hello extension to negotiate supported signing algorithms (including hash) more flexibly.

[RFC 5246 A.7 Changes to RFC 4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-A.7)

> RFC 4492 [TLSECC] adds Elliptic Curve cipher suites to TLS.  This
> document changes some of the structures used in that document.  This
> section details the required changes for implementors of both RFC
> 4492 and TLS 1.2.  Implementors of TLS 1.2 who are not implementing
> RFC 4492 do not need to read this section.
>
> This document adds a "signature_algorithm" field to the digitally-
> signed element in order to identify the signature and digest
> algorithms used to create a signature.  This change applies to
> digital signatures formed using ECDSA as well, thus allowing ECDSA
> signatures to be used with digest algorithms other than SHA-1,
> provided such use is compatible with the certificate and any
> restrictions imposed by future revisions of [PKIX].
>
> As described in Sections 7.4.2 and 7.4.6, the restrictions on the
> signature algorithms used to sign certificates are no longer tied to
> the cipher suite (when used by the server) or the
> ClientCertificateType (when used by the client).  Thus, the
> restrictions on the algorithm used to sign certificates specified in
> Sections 2 and 3 of RFC 4492 are also relaxed.  As in this document,
> the restrictions on the keys in the end-entity certificate remain.

In particular [RFC 5246 4.7 Cryptographic Attributes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-4.7)

> A digitally-signed element is encoded as a struct DigitallySigned:
>
> ```
>   struct {
>      SignatureAndHashAlgorithm algorithm;
>      opaque signature<0..2^16-1>;
>   } DigitallySigned;
> ```
>
> The algorithm field specifies the algorithm used (see Section
> 7.4.1.4.1 for the definition of this field).  Note that the
> introduction of the algorithm field is a change from previous
> versions. .... RSA .... DSA ....

Additional points:

- the server signs its ECDHE public key *and the curve* (which in practice,
  especially for Suite B, is named form rather than explicit, thus quite small)
  **(edit, thanks David)** as well as the nonces, with at least the client nonce proving freshness
- Suite B requirements are set by NSA not NIST. IIRC Suite B
  required SHA256 and SHA384 *before* NIST "deprecated" SHA1.
- RFC 5430 was obsoleted by [RFC 6460](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6460)
  which requires TLS1.2 and GCM as well as ECDHE-ECDSA.

Comment: _Suite B requirements are set by NSA not NIST. IIRC Suite B required SHA256 and SHA384 before NIST "deprecated" SHA1_: This also seems to imply that NIST specified the need to use alternative hash functions even before TLS 1.2 (with the provision to select a hash function other than SHA1) RFC was in place (?)

Comment: to add to your additional point number 1: the server signs: (ClientHello.random | ServerHello.random | ServerKeyExchange.params ) where params are the ecdhe pubkey (and its length) and the name of the curve.

Comment: @user13311 NIST established the SHA-2 hashes as *optional* (not required) in 2002, and defined RSA and expanded DSA signatures 
using them (or rather their sizes) in 186-3 proposed in 2006 but not finalized until 2009. It also stated a policy in 
2006 that SHA1 should not be used for (new) signatures after 2010, but had to relax that to 2013. RFC 5246 came out in 2008,
so it was before NIST's attempted deadline and well before their actual deadline. And the industry didn't really get it done until this year.

Comment: @David edited. Note ECDHE params are *usually* a standard curve "name" (encoded as a number), but *can* be "explicit" 
with all the parameters of a Weierstrauss prime or binary curve: prime or size and polynomial, coefficients a and b, base point, order and cofactor.